# Matplotlib does not generate some special latex-symbols due to a CalledProcessError with dvipng

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, julia

I am trying to generate the "@"-symbol in a Julia plot generated with matplotlib (using PyPlot). But I get:

> CalledProcessError: "Command '['dvipng', etc. returned non-zero exit status 2".

Everything seems to work fine with MikTex and Latex, so I assume the problem is with Julia and/or Matplotlib. I reinstalled Julia and Matplotlib; I also removed the …/matplotlib/tex.cache map. But the problem remains.

Here is a minimal example (in Julia):

```
using PyPlot  
PyPlot.matplotlib.rc("text", usetex = "True") 
text(0.2,0.8,"ABC, \$P_t\$, \$\\pi_t\$")
text(0.2,0.6,"\$\\copyright\$")
savefig("MinimalExample.pdf")
```

I get a plot with the text "ABC, P_t, \pi_t" (printed exactly as in a Latex document). But it does not include a line with the copyright-sign, and trying to include a copyright-sign yields the following `CalledProcessError`:

> Command '['dvipng', '-bg', 'Transparent', '-D', '100.0', '-T', 'tight', '-o', 'C:\Users\…\.matplotlib\tex.cache\b7646e340176ce1b058ce8ff1ee96282.png', 'C:\Users\…\.matplotlib\tex.cache\170052df7cdbf1343c56362652ecb09f.dvi']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: On my ubuntu system your code works. (Sorry but can't help further then to say that at least your code is correct)

Comment: This seems to be a known problem: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10272

Comment: Thank you for editing, @Engineero! The problem may indeed be related to [https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10272](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10272). But it seems to me that it has not been solved yet…